# Failed at the @pact-foundation/pact-core@13.13.8

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, web-api-testing, pact

Could anyone help me with installing pact-js

I'm trying to install @pact-foundation/pact. And I got an error in any version pact after 9 -
**Failed at the @pact-foundation/pact-core@13.13.8 install script**

node version - 14.20.0
npm 6.14.17
angular 15.2.2

Answer (score 0):

The answer was very simple - latest stable node version